# CreateThread Call Giving Error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to start a thread in a class which in turn will call a function which is the member of the same class. Following is the sample code I want to build.

```
void CM::ExecuteIt()
{
// Some Calculations

if(/*Condition*/)
{
hThreadArray = CreateThread( 
                NULL,                   // default security attributes
                0,                      // use default stack size  
                MyThreadFunction,       // thread function name
                (LPVOID)&nProcessImage,          // argument to thread function 
                0,                      // use default creation flags 
                &dwThreadIdArray);
}
}

void CM::MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) 
    { 
    HANDLE hStdout;
    PMYDATA pDataArray;
// Some calculations that needs to be done
    }
```

but while building it i am getting the following Error
"Error  16  error C3867: 'CM::MyThreadFunction': function call missing argument list; use '&CM::MyThreadFunction' to create a pointer to member"

I am not sure how I am doing it wrong. Can somebody please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a non-static member to `CreateThread`. The function you pass must be a stand-alone non-member function, or else a static member function. A common approach would go something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  void StartThread() {
    CreateThread(..., ThreadProcTrampoline, this, ...);
  }

  static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProcTrampoline(LPVOID param) {
    MyClass* self = static_cast<MyClass*>(param);
    return self->RealThreadProc();
  }

  DWORD RealThreadProc();
};
```

Any data you want to pass to the thread procedure, you would store as data members of the class.

Alternatively, since you tagged your question `C++11`, use `std::thread`. It's much more flexible in what you can pass along.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!! removed the error by passing a stand alone non member fuction.